# What are the tradeoffs associated with the initialization syntax of the maximum value of an integer?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, evm

What are the tradeoffs associated with using the following syntax to define the maximum value possible of an integer:

`uint256 max = type(uint256).max;`

as opposed to:

`uint256 max = 2**256 - 1`;?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any significance difference, other than for readibility reasons. At the end of the day, `max` will represent the largest number that `uint256` can be defined with and it doesn't matter to the EVM.

Here is btw other ways to represent the max of uint256 if you're interested: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/using-the-maximum-integer-in-solidity/3000/7

Cheers~